# Installing sqlite on windows xp for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I've been trying to follow [this](http://andrewgertig.com/2010/09/install-ruby-on-rails-on-a-pc-done-rubyonrails/) guide to installing ruby and rails on my new machine. I'm having problems, however, when it comes to the sqlite gem. I installed the gem, which seemed to work perfectly. Then, however, it tells me to download a zip file from http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_7_3.zip. When I do, the file is downloaded, but it doesn't seem to be a zip file. It has the icon of a microsoft word file, and clicking on it opens up Word but the file isn't opened, it just shows error messages. There is no option to extract the file, which is what the guide says to do. Is this a problem with sqlite or my machine?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your download was corrupt or something, I get a zip file with 2 items in it:

> sqlite3.dll   sqlite3.def

Worth trying again.

Could it be a firewall issue, are you going via your work firewall/web-proxy?

Regards,
Chris

PS I do see the site changing - it was 3.7.2 a few days ago, 3.7.3 in your message but 3.7.4 on the site now: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to download it a couple of times. It must be a problem with my computer.

Comment: @benny: Maybe you've got a virus that's screwing around there? Others are successfully downloading it so it's not corrupt at source…

Comment: and donal - I've found it was something about how my computer handles zip files. I downloaded 7zip and it worked fine. Thankyou for your help anyway.